# Configuring permit for 2 user models in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I've been busting myself for a ton of hours now on how to do this.

I have 2 models.

```
intern.rb
company.rb
```

I've been able to add custom fields on registration, for me that was :name. I did that by adding:

```
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

def configure_permitted_parameters
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |i| i.permit(:email, :password, :name) }
end
```

I've been reading up on the devise readme and trying to understand how to add it so it's specific to one user model. But I get an error every single time.

I tried creating a controller called:

```
interns_controller.rb
```

with the code:

```
class Intern::ParameterSanitizer < Devise::ParameterSanitizer
 def sign_up
  default_params.permit(:email, :password, :name)
 end
end
```

and then adding this into the

```
application_controller.rb
```

code:

```
protected

def devise_parameter_sanitizer
if resource_class == Intern
  Intern::ParameterSanitizer.new(Intern, :intern, params)
else
  super 
end
end
```

however I get an error. What am I doing wrong here?
Image with error: http://s12.postimg.org/fqpwyzzdp/Screen_Shot_2014_06_17_at_15_41_58.png

Comment: Providing the error and the stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: Looks like your `Intern::ParameterSanitizer` class was never loaded. If you put it in a custom dir like `/lib`, you'll need to add that to `config.autoload_paths` in `/config/application.rb`, or put in in `app/models/concerns` or someplace like that that autoloads your code.

Comment: @Unixmonkey but shouldn't it work as it inherits from devise::paramatersenitizer ?

Comment: Doesn't matter if the file never gets loaded. Rails auto-`require`'s files in certain directories, and won't ever see your code if it is outside there, unless it is manually required. If you want to be explicit, then you can add to the top of `application_controller.rb`: `require Rails.root.join('lib','intern_parameter_sanitizer')`. Also, it looks from your question that you named it `interns_controller.rb`, that's not right. I think you are mishmashing your controller and sanitizer files, which should be separate.

Comment: @Unixmonkey *whistles* what's a sanitizer file?